# Flutter share facebook : 'init()' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (FBSDKShareKit.ShareDialog)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, fbsdksharekit

I want to share posts from my flutter app to social media platforms like facebook.

I've used [flutter_share_me](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me) package ( version 1.2.0 ),
my Android project is working well for Facebook sharing.

But when I build my iOS project, the building is failed due to the following errors

in sharefacebook function of SwiftFlutterShareMePlugin.swift file.

> 'init()' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
> (FBSDKShareKit.ShareDialog)

```
func sharefacebook(message:Dictionary<String,Any>, result: @escaping FlutterResult)  {
    let viewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController
    let shareDialog=ShareDialog() // **this line make the error**
    let shareContent = ShareLinkContent()
    shareContent.contentURL = URL.init(string: message["url"] as! String)!
    shareContent.quote = message["msg"] as? String
    shareDialog.mode = .automatic
    ShareDialog(fromViewController: viewController, content: shareContent, delegate: self).show()
    result("Sucess")

}
```

Please help me with how to solve this issue.

I found other Flutter developers are also meet [similar issues](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/579) when they try to share their posts to Facebook using other packages like [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package.

> https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've update SwiftFlutterShareMePlugin.swift of flutter_share_me package(version 1.2.0) file as following, and the iOS project is working for facebook sharing.

```
func sharefacebook(message:Dictionary<String,Any>, result: @escaping FlutterResult)  {
    let viewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController
    
    let shareContent = ShareLinkContent()
    shareContent.contentURL = URL.init(string: message["url"] as! String)!
    shareContent.quote = message["msg"] as? String
    ShareDialog(viewController: viewController, content: shareContent, delegate: self).show()
    result("Sucess")
    
}
```

I think the problem is because some functions of FBSDKShareKit are deprecated by its version up.